# clang + libc++: combination of make_tuple with make_shared leads to early object destruction

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, clang, libc++

I've lost almost all day tracking bug in my program. For some reason, my implementation of `std::apply` in terms of c++11 was faulty: arguments to the underlying function somehow got *empty* in the middle of call. Good example is `std::unique_ptr` that after call to a makeshift function (below, `foo()`) was always `empty()` in the body of called function.

I've dumbed down my code to a simple test case:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

struct Foo
{
    Foo()
    {
        std::cout << "Foo()" << std::endl;
    }

    ~Foo()
    {
        std::cout << "~Foo()" << std::endl;
    }
};

template <typename ...Args>
void foo(Args && ...args)
{
    using TupleType = decltype(std::make_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args)...));

    std::cout << "Point #1" << std::endl;

    /// Package arguments to a function.
    auto && packaged_args = std::make_shared<TupleType>(std::make_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args)...));

    std::cout << "Point #2" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<Foo> foo_var{new Foo};

    foo(std::move(foo_var));
    return 0;
}
```

If compiled with **clang** together with **libc++** (-stdlib=libc++) the results are:

```
Foo()
Point #1
~Foo()
Point #2
```

---

Live example on [coliru.stacked-crooked.com](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cbdf2ded17c853d6)

---

The results are obviously incorrect. If compiled with [clang, but **without libc++**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/97742a75b6790c74), or if compiled with [gcc](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e706365eabc20dbe), the results are as expected:

```
Foo()
Point #1
Point #2
~Foo()
```

---

I found a laughable workaround for the combination of **clang** and **libc++**, replace:

```
auto && packaged_args = std::make_shared<TupleType>(std::make_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
```

with:

```
std::shared_ptr<TupleType> packaged_args{new TupleType(std::make_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args)...))};
```

and it again works as expected.

---

Live example on [coliru.stacked-crooked.com](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6e702afb89e1234f)

---

The qustion is: is it an UB, so that both compilers are right with the wrong code or the code is okay and this is a bug?

Comment: I'll start debugging this tonight. PS We have a bugzilla too :-P

Comment: Coliru's Clang is 3.8. Seems to be fixed in Wandbox's 3.9.1.

Comment: @EricWF, sorry not posting directry there, I'm not 100% sure my program is without flaws.

Comment: FWIW It seems that this problem only occurs with really old versions of libc++. Testing against trunk and the issue does not reproduce.

Comment: @EricWF, unfortunately, it affects the version that comes with `FreeBSD 11.0-STABLE`, built-in.

Comment: @GreenScape What's the value of _LIBCPP_VERSION on FreeBSD 11?

Comment: @GreenScape Nevermind. It appears to be present in 3.8 but fixed in 3.9. I suspect that FreeBSD 11 uses <= 3.8. Sorry about the bug.

Comment: @EricWF, no problem, I love what you're doing anyway (clang > gcc) ;).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in libc++'s tuple implementation.

The bug exists in Libc++ <= 3.8, but has been fixed by my tuple rewrite in 3.9.

Sorry about the bug; it appears the best/only way to avoid it is upgrade.